# Need to Conver PBF Format ("Protocolbuffer Binary Format") to SQLite data Base on Android Device

Tags: java, android, sqlite, openstreetmap

I need to read map data from  PBF Format ("Protocolbuffer Binary Format") and need to copy to SQLite database in android.

There are several ways to do this on desktop is available but i want to do this with my android application.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: want to read data from .pbf file and store to sqlite database and than want to show on map

Comment: Are you really sure that you want to perform this conversion on mobile devices instead of shipping already pre-processed map files?

Comment: yes i want to do this..?is it possible..?

Comment: You can compile GDAL for android (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid) and use it with the osm driver to get a spatialite (http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html)